# blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource : Errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http, https, cors

In my E-commerce mern app, its perfectly work in my `http://localhost:****`. When i deployed backend as HTTPS, GET method was working while POST was not. The error showing blocked by cors policy.

Frontend(axiosconfig) -

```
const getTokenFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("user") ?
                 JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) : null;

export const config = {
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${getTokenFromLocalStorage !== null ? getTokenFromLocalStorage.token : ""}`,
        Accept: "application/json",
    }
}
```

Uploadservice -

```
 import axios from "axios";
 import { base_url } from "../../utils/base_url";
 import { config } from "../../utils/axiosconfig";

 const uploadImg = async (data) => {
          const response = await axios.post(`${base_url}upload/`, data, config)
          return response.data
      }

 const uploadService = {
     uploadImg
 }

 export default uploadService
```

Backend -
const express = require('express')
const dbConnect = require('./config/dbConnect')
const app = express()

```
require('dotenv').config()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
const authRouter = require('./routes/authRoute')
const productRouter = require('./routes/productRoute')
const blogRouter = require('./routes/blogRoute')
const categoryRouter = require('./routes/prodcategoryRouter')
const bcategoryRouter = require('./routes/blogCatRoute')
const brandRouter = require('./routes/brandRoute')
const colorRouter = require('./routes/colorRoute')
const enqRouter = require('./routes/enqRoutes')
const uploadRouter = require('./routes/uploadRoute')
const couponRouter = require('./routes/couponRoute')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const { notFound, errorHandler } = require('./middlewares/errorHandler')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const cors = require('cors')
dbConnect()

app.use(morgan("dev"))
app.use(cors())

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(cookieParser())

app.use('/api/user', authRouter)
app.use('/api/product', productRouter)
app.use('/api/blog', blogRouter)
app.use('/api/category', categoryRouter)
app.use('/api/blogcategory', bcategoryRouter)
app.use('/api/brand', brandRouter)
app.use('/api/coupon', couponRouter)
app.use('/api/color', colorRouter)
app.use('/api/enquiry', enqRouter)
app.use('/api/upload', uploadRouter)

app.use(notFound)
app.use(errorHandler)

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running at PORT ${PORT}`);
})
```

Comment: How about testing get and post from postman or something similar? Does that work for you? Maybe this one helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i?rq=2

Answer (score 0):

for your web server do you use nginx or apache ?

if nginx try to add :

```
location / {
   add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin 'your_domain';
}
```

if apache try to add :

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "your_domain"
```

Comment: where can i add this ? is it index.js in server

Comment: You use nginx or apache for your webserver ? If you're not in prod but still in dev you can try to use a proxy pass with apache or nginx to redirect your localhost to your node application. If it doesn't work, add the lines in my last message